# dihedral angles of non-regulare icosahedron given its coordinates

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d

I have the coordinates (3D) of the vertices of an icosahedron (not a regular one) and I want to find all dihedral angles. I am fine with just equations to which they need to fulfill as I would think that you need information of many/all vertices before you can calculate one of the dihedral angles (so not expecting a closed form formula).

Anyone here that has ideas how to find these equation or which mathematical theory I need to dive into to solve this?

thanks in advance

Comment: HINT. If $ABC$ is a triangle, then $(A-C)\times(B-C)$ is a vector perpendicular to the plane of the triangle.

Comment: HINT 2. The angle between two planes is the same as the angle between  their normal vectors.